# Converting NSDate using the NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a set of dates as `NSString`s. They are in the next format: `1980/9/26 17:23:00`. The problem is that the month doesn't include a zero for months from 1 to 9. So some of the dates are `1980/9/26 17:23:00` and some are `1980/12/26 17:23:00`. The date formatter either gets a `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` or `yyyy/m/dd hh:mm:ss`.

Whichever of these two formats I use, I can't format both date types. Here is the code I used by the way:

```
-(NSString *) convertDate : (NSString *) unformatted
{

//Format the Date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:unformatted];

//Format the Calendar
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSCalendar *persian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:@"persian"];
[f setCalendar:persian];
[f setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

NSString *formattedDate = [f stringFromDate:date];
//Replace english strings with farsi strings
formattedDate=[formattedDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Farvardin" withString:@"فروردین"];
formattedDate=[formattedDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Ordibehesht" withString:@"اردیبهشت"];
formattedDate=[formattedDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Khordad" withString:@"خرداد"];
formattedDate=[formattedDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Tir" withString:@"تیر"];
formattedDate=[formattedDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Mordad" withString:@"مرداد"];
formattedDate=[formattedDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Shahrivar" withString:@"شهریور"];
formattedDate=[formattedDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Mehr" withString:@"مهر"];
formattedDate=[formattedDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Aban" withString:@"آبان"];
formattedDate=[formattedDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Azar" withString:@"آذر"];
formattedDate=[formattedDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Dey" withString:@"دی"];
formattedDate=[formattedDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Bahman" withString:@"بهمن"];
formattedDate=[formattedDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Esfand" withString:@"اسفند"];
formattedDate=[formattedDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"AP" withString:@""];

return formattedDate;
}
```

Comment: Bookmark [this date format page](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns), you'll need it in the future!

Comment: I think you mean Gregorian rather than Georgian, and that's not a format as such - it's a calendar system. You can format a Gregorian date in any way you like. I also suspect that if you use the right approach, you won't need to replace the month names yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `MM` for months. Also, you need to use `HH` for hours. Try this format: `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: @user1665325, Can you, please, describe how `unformatted` string looks like? And how should `formattedDate` string look like?

Comment: The unforamatted has is in this form: 1980/9/26 17:23:00 or 1980/12/26 17:23:00. formatted date is gonna be in persian calendar form. The problem is that the month could be two digits or one digit. the date formatter either detects one digit with M or two digits with MM.

Comment: @user1665325, I updated my answer. Now it should work.